# How should I replace the numpy array in this code?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a program that creates a linear gradient but uses numpy arrays. This cannot be used because the numpy library takes up too much space on the microcontroller. Is there a way to replace the numpy.array with something else?

```
import numpy as np

def colorFade(c1, c2, mix=0):
    c1 = np.array(c1)
    c2 = np.array(c2)
    print(tuple((1-mix)*c1 + mix*c2))

c1 = (0, 0, 200)
c2 = (200, 0, 200)
n = 500

for x in range(n+1):
    colorFade(c1,c2,x/n)
```

I attempted to change the array to a tuple and a list but both failed and gave this error:
`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`
The numpy.array module does not give this error.

Comment: For lists (and strings), `*` is defined as repeat, which only makes sense for an integer. `+` is join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists and tuples don't automatically apply arithmetic operations to each element, you have to write that explicitly.

```
def colorFade(c1, c2, mix=0):
    print(tuple((1-mix)*e1 + mix*e2 for e1, e2 in zip(c1, c2)))
```